# Why is INPUT field size different across platforms? OS X vs Windows?

Tags: 7, forms, hooks, theming

I have a drupal created form where I have set the size of the form:

```
$form['myform']['#size'] = 22;
```

Now on my windows machine on Chrome / FF / IE / Safari it is a specific size, visually.

When I go to view the same form on my Macbook the same INPUT field is significantly smaller in Chrome / FF / Safari on OS X ??? Even though both obviously have the size = 22 setting?

Why is it not rendering the same size across all platforms??

Comment: I'd say this is a http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq question, since it deals more with the HTML, CSS aspects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Size is the char amount that goes into the input field. If you want to style it, use CSS.

```
.inputbox{
  border: 1px solid #666;
  width: 210px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are differences in how the two platforms render content: [THE WINDOWS/MAC FONT-SIZE PROBLEM](http://www.rfwilmut.clara.net/about/fonts.html). I'm afraid this is a long standing issue that many will say is the fault of Windows rather than the Mac due to how things are rendered on the two systems. If you're really keen on getting the best results in making your forms look consistent across browsers/platforms consider using css3: [Design a Prettier Web Form with CSS 3](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/design-a-prettier-web-form-with-css-3/).